# Method to serialize custom object to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

Generally, we can define `__str__` method to make `str(obj)` return what we want.

But now I want to define my Model object to return a default JSON string when using `json.dumps(obj)`.

Is there any nice way for me to declare a method in the class to do this?

```
class MyClass:
    ...
    def __json__(self):
        return {'name': self.name, 'age': self.age}

obj = MyClass()

json.dumps(obj) # returns the same as json.dumps(obj.__json__)
```

Comment: You can use a custom JSONEncoder

Comment: What needs to happen when the string gets `loads`'d?

Comment: I don't concern about that, `loads` returns `dict` is ok. @user2357112

Comment: The [python json module docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) includes short examples for extending to custom classes. Their example is complex numbers. Could you try adapting that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you only need Python -> JSON, it's simple to write a JSONEncoder class that calls such a method for any object:

```
class AutoJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj._json()
        except AttributeError:
            return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

You can then use the class directly `AutoJSONEncoder().encode(obj)` or through the `dumps` interface `json.dumps(obj, cls=AutoJSONEncoder)`.

The reverse direction requires at least a list of classes for which to call a `_fromjson` method.

(Note: `__foo__` names are reserved so you shouldn't define them for your own purposes. `__bar` invokes name mangling, which probably isn't what you want.)

Comment: Well, this is I want. But I tried the code, it seems not works by default, how can it be?

Comment: You need to make sure you are using the custom class instead of the default JSONEncoder. You can pass the class name to `json.dumps` using the `cls` parameter. If you already have a bunch of `dumps` calls and don't want to add it to all of them, you can define your own using `dumps = lambda obj: json.dumps(obj, cls=AutoJSONEncoder)`.

Comment: OK, thanks alot! I edited your answer to add the call method.

Comment: For more, when I tried `AutoJSONEncoder().encode([obj1, obj2])`, I got an error, can this be possible?

Comment: It raises `[<...>] is not JSON serializable`, `Exception Type: TypeError`, I just want it automatically cascading, is that possible?  @otus

Comment: @fish_ball, that kind of code (e.g. [this](https://gist.github.com/jvarho/f3967afb112aa4a6de55)) works for me. You should show more code and perhaps ask a new question if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 7):

```
import json


class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """
    JSONEncoder subclass that leverages an object's `__json__()` method,
    if available, to obtain its default JSON representation. 

    """
    def default(self, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, '__json__'):
            return obj.__json__()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


class MyClass(object):
    name = 'John'
    age = 30

    def __json__(self):
        return {'name': self.name, 'age': self.age}

>>> json.dumps(MyClass(), cls=MyEncoder)
{"age": 30, "name": "John"}
```